# Missing Week in PHP's DateTime->modify('next week')

Tags: php, datetime, week-number

I think I am fully aware of ISO 8601 and that the first week of a year is the week that has a Monday in it. However I came across a strange behavior in PHP (5.6) DateTime Class.

Here is my code:

```
$start = new DateTime('2009-01-01 00:00');
$end = new DateTime();
$point = $start;

while($point <= $end){
   echo $point->format('YW');
   $point = $point->modify('next week');
}
```

This puts out correctly

```
200901
200902
200903
...
```

But if I pick as a start date something earlier in 2008 like `$start = new DateTime('2008-01-01 00:00');` then I get a different result:

```
...
200852
200801 // <=== 2008??
200902   
200903
...
```

Is this a PHP bug or am I'm missing something here?

Comment: its because it first week of 2009, try `echo $point->format('YW') ."  --> ". $point->format('Y-m-d');` hope you will understand the thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tinkered with this and finally figured it out

```
$start = new DateTime('2008-12-29 00:00');
$end = new DateTime('2009-01-7 00:00');
$point = $start;

while($point <= $end){
   echo $point->format('YW') . "\t";
   echo $point->format('m-d-Y')  . "\n";
   $point = $point->modify('next week');
}
```

So the first date here is `2008-12-29`. Thus `Y` is correct. But `2008-12-29` is also **week 1**. So the `W` is also correct

https://3v4l.org/JZtqa

Comment: Then this is a PHP bug. If you iterate through a year by weeks you would expect it to correctly calculate the 53rd week, right?

Comment: @StevenM It's not a bug. That's actually how ISO8601 sees it. [Check out this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) and you'll note that  `Mon 29 Dec 2008` is `2009-W01-1`

Comment: Yes, exactly - but PHP makes that the first week in *2008* not 2009....

Comment: @StevenM No. 12-29-2008 is still in 2008. That's what `Y` does. If you use `o` instead (ISO8601 year) you'll see it's in 2009. The bug is in your script, not PHP https://3v4l.org/nEMmj

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug! Inspired by @Machavity and based on this [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562270/php-datew-vs-mysql-yearweeknow) I found a solution:

```
echo $point->format('oW');
```

instead of

```
echo $point->format('YW')
```

produces:

```
...
200852
200901
200902
...
```

no matter when the start date is. It's really a RTM case, as the PHP manual states:

> **o** ==>
>   ISO-8601 year number. This has the same value as Y, except that if the
>   ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is
>   used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)